# Open image in modal foundation

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I want to open an img in a modal with foundation.

I have the following code:

```
<img src="images/medium/Pluto.jpg" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px; max-height:150px;max-width:150px"/>
```

and

```
<div id="modalDialogPhotoView" class="reveal-modal " data-reveal>       
</div>
```

I will create an event onclick on the photo and show that photo in the modalDialogPhotoView.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an ID to the image, for example:

```
<img id="image1" src="images/medium/Pluto.jpg" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px; max-height:150px;max-width:150px"/>
```

Then in javascript try this:

```
// Put the photo in the modal and show that modal if hidden
var appendImgToModal = function(event) {
    $('#image1').appendTo($('#modalDialogPhotoView'));
    $('#image1').show();
}
// Set the function to call when the user clicks the photo
$('#image1').on('click', appendImgToModal);
```